# How to cancel a long-running query when using rust-sqlx/tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx

I am migrating from `rusqlite` where I was using `get_interrupt_handle` to abort a query immediately from another thread (when the user changed the filter parameters).

Here's an example of my current code. The best I can do is add an interrupt check before every `await` but that doesn't help if the initial query is taking ages to return the first result.

```rust
struct Query {
    title: String,
}

fn start_async(requests: crossbeam::channel::Receiver<Query>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let runtime = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
            .enable_all()
            .build()
            .unwrap();
        runtime.block_on(run_db_thread(requests));
    });
}

async fn run_db_thread(requests: crossbeam::channel::Sender<Query>) {
    let connection = SqliteConnection::connect("test.sqlite").await?;
    loop {
        if let Ok(query) = requests.recv() {
            do_query(&connection, &query).await?;
        }
    }
}

async fn do_query(connection: &SqliteConnection, query: &Query) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut stream = sqlx::query("SELECT title, authors, series FROM Books where title like ?")
        .bind(&format!("%{}%", query.title))
        .fetch(&connection);
    while let Some(row) = stream.next().await {
        let (title, authors, series) = row?;
        println!("{} {} {}", title, authors, series);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to interrupt a running sqlx execution when a new `Query` arrives in the channel? I'd be happy to send a signal separately if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All** futures are inherently cancellable — this is one of the benefits (and hazards) of `async` over blocking multithreaded code. You simply drop the future instead of polling it further.

The first thing you will need to do is change from a blocking channel to an `async` channel — this allows checking the channel to be mixed with running the query. Then, you can use various future manipulating tools to decide whether or not to *continue* running the query. I've decided to do this with `select!`, which polls several futures and runs code according to whichever one completes first.

(There might be a better tool for this; I am familiar with how async works but haven't written a lot of complex async code.)

```rust
use futures::future::OptionFuture;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn run_db_thread(mut requests: mpsc::Receiver<Query>) {
    // This variable holds the current query being run, if there is one
    let mut current_query_future = OptionFuture::default();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            // If we receive a new query, replace the current query with it.
            Some(query) = requests.recv() => {
                println!("Starting new query {query:?}");
                current_query_future = OptionFuture::from(Some(Box::pin(async move {
                    let answer = do_query(&query).await;
                    println!("Finished query {query:?} => {answer:?}");
                    answer
                })));
                // Note that we did not `.await` the new future.
            }

            // Poll the current query future, and check if it is done yet.
            Some(_answer) = &mut current_query_future => {
                // Stop polling the completed future.
                current_query_future = None.into();
            }

            // We get here if both of the above branches saw None, which means that the
            // channel is closed, *and* there is no query to run.
            else => {
                println!("Channel closed; run_db_thread() exiting");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Example to drive the loop.
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel(1);
    tokio::spawn(run_db_thread(receiver));

    for (i, delay) in [1000, 1000, 1, 1, 1, 1000, 1000].into_iter().enumerate() {
        sender.send(Query(i)).await.unwrap();
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;
    }
    println!("main() exiting");
}

// Skeleton data types to make the example compile
#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Query(usize);
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Answer;
async fn do_query(_q: &Query) -> Answer {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
    Answer
}
```

This example code prints:

```rust
Starting new query Query(0)
Finished query Query(0) => Answer
Starting new query Query(1)
Finished query Query(1) => Answer
Starting new query Query(2)
Starting new query Query(3)
Starting new query Query(4)
Starting new query Query(5)
Finished query Query(5) => Answer
Starting new query Query(6)
Finished query Query(6) => Answer
main() exiting
```

That is, queries 0, 1, 5, and 6 completed, but queries 2, 3, and 4 were cancelled by a new query arriving before they could complete.